# Leaflet.draw Coordinates are not updating after Edit

Tags: leaflet

I'm using the [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin and I'm trying to get updated coordinates of shape after editing corner positions

```
map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
    // Update db to save latest changes.
    var layers = e.layers;

    layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        alert(layer.feature.geometry.coordinates.toString());
    });
});
```

After editing, this code is executing as you know.. But `layer.feature.geometry.coordinates` is giving me **old** coordinates..

Is it a bug or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Check `layer.getLatLngs().toString()` method, is seems to work. Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UXvfE/).

Comment: `map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
    // Update db to save latest changes.
    var layers = e.layers;
    
    layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        alert(layer.getLatLngs().toString());
    });
}); `

Here i have error at "alert(layer.getLatLngs().toString());"

The error is 10-18 15:44:53.940: E/Web Console(2512): 
**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getLatLngs' at file:///android_asset/www/main.html:113**

Comment: Try to change `leaflet.js` and `leaflet.draw.js` to the same versions applied in JSFiddle. You will find links in `External Resources` section in left panel.

Comment: I updated my js files.. Now it is working good but I have new problem      
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451007/uncaught-typeerror-objectobject-object-has-no-method-x-at-file-y-error