# Uncaught TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method 'x' at file y Error

Tags: javascript, android, leaflet

I'm using LeafLet in Android and I'm trying to show edited coordinates in alert.

**HEAD**

```
<head>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.draw.css" />
 <script src="leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="leaflet.draw.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="tmp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
 <script src="http://matchingnotes.com/javascripts/leaflet-google.js"></script>
 <script src="webintent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <style type="text/css">
 #map { height: 100%;
 width: 100%; }
</style>

</head>
```

Here is my function

```
map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
    // Update db to save latest changes.
    var layers = e.layers;

    layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
       alert(layer.getLatLngs().toString());  //this is 114. command line
    });
});
```

When i try this on web browser, it is working good.. But when I try this in Android, I'm getting this error.

Any suggestion ?

10-18 16:22:05.240: E/Web Console(4459): **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getLatLngs' at file:///android_asset/www/main.html:114**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andy thanks for solution but it is not typo.
If you are working with **Markers**, you have to use **getLatLng()** function because Marker has only one LatLng.
If you are working with **more than** 1 point like polygon, polyline, you have to use **getLatLngs()** function.  I was working with Marker and i was trying to use getLatLngs() with Marker. That was the problem

Comment: Yes, it was confusing to me when you approved typo.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. It should be `alert(layer.getLatLng().toString());`.

Comment: Thanks for solution. It is working now but i didn't understand how can it work on browser without any error ?

Comment: It looks like author changed methods in some version.